# Connection Failure error with facebook share on Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-share

I'm trying to implement facebook share on Android using Facebook SDK 4.41.0
However, I'm facing the following issue: When the share dialog should appear, it is immediately closed and the OnError callback method is throwing the following error

```
CONNECTION_FAILURE: CONNECTION_FAILURE
    at com.facebook.internal.NativeProtocol.getExceptionFromErrorData(NativeProtocol.java:811)
    at com.facebook.share.internal.ShareInternalUtility.handleActivityResult(ShareInternalUtility.java:169)
    at com.facebook.share.internal.ShareInternalUtility$3.onActivityResult(ShareInternalUtility.java:261)
    at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl.onActivityResult(CallbackManagerImpl.java:91)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:160)
```

Any idea about what can be failing?

This are some relevant code snippets:

```
 facebookCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()
    if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent::class.java)) {
        val url = "https://www.example.com"
        url?.let {
            val shareUri = it.toUri()
            val content = ShareLinkContent.Builder().setContentUrl(shareUri).build()
            val dialog = ShareDialog(this)
            dialog.registerCallback(facebookCallbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result> {
                override fun onSuccess(result: Sharer.Result?) {
                    Timber.i("Success on Facebook share")
                }

                override fun onCancel() {
                    Timber.i("Facebook cancelled")
                }

                override fun onError(error: FacebookException?) {
                    Timber.e(error, "facebook  share failed")
                }
            })
            dialog.show(content)
```

Comment: Are your device connected to the internet?

Comment: Yes. I'm connected to internet. The rest of the app is working fine and I'm able to use chrome to access any random site.
Don't know if I need to add any special adapter for okhttp / retrofit like with glide.